# Can anyone solve this?

Tags: pytorch

torch.tensor(2,require_grad=True)

> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > >        torch.tensor(2,require_grad=True)
> > >
> > > TypeError: tensor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'require_grad'

Answer (score 3):

It's actually:

> require**s**_grad